# pandas - with restructuring data in data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that has data in format

> time       | name   | value
>
> ---
>
> 01/01/1970 | A      | 1
>      02/01/1970 | A      | 2
>      03/01/1970 | A      | 1
>      01/01/1970 | B      | 5
>      02/01/1970 | B      | 3

I what to change this data to something like

> time       | A      | B
>
> ---
>
> 01/01/1970 | 1      | 5
>      02/01/1970 | 2      | 3
>      03/01/1970 | 1      | NA

How can I achieve this in pandas? I have tried groupby on dataframe and then joining but its coming out right. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) ([doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)):

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
     'time': ['01/01/1970', '02/01/1970', '03/01/1970', '01/01/1970', '02/01/1970'],
     'value': [1, 2, 1, 5, 3]})

print(df.pivot(index='time', columns='name', values='value'))
```

yields

```
            A   B
time             
01/01/1970  1   5
02/01/1970  2   3
03/01/1970  1 NaN
```

Note that `time` is now the index. If you wish to make it a column, call `reset_index()`:

```
df.pivot(index='time', columns='name', values='value').reset_index()
# name        time  A   B
# 0     01/01/1970  1   5
# 1     02/01/1970  2   3
# 2     03/01/1970  1 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a million...You answer has solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use the .pivot function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : [0,1,2,3],
'name': ['A','A', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [10,20,30,40]})

df.pivot(index = 'time', columns = 'name', values = 'value')
```